# Best practices for quad-copter designing

Tags: quadcopter, uav, multi-rotor, ardupilot

What are the some of the best practices for placing the components (including battery, GPS, flight-controller, wires, receiver etc.) on the air-frame of an 'X' quad-copter to ensure the minimum power loss as a result of overburdening of the flight controller. Also, how can we test that CG is not disturbed after placing the components.

Comment: how do you determine the CG before placing the components? ... do the same after placement

Comment: Your cog cannot be moved as long as everything is placed perfectly symmetrically...which no-one can promise it is, where you expect it to be...thus you must find it anyways.